# Spell check with google dictionary

Tags: android-layout, dictionary, android, android-toast

I am creating an application in which I have to check the word typed by user is correct   or not using Google dictionary. If the word typed by user is correct, then a toast will be displayed. I am not getting any proper solution on my Google search. So please give me some idea if it is possible.

Comment: Please share your attempted solution. For more information, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
    isSpellCorrect = false;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i) {
        // Returned suggestions are contained in SuggestionsInfo
        final int len = arg0[i].getSuggestionsCount();
        if(editText1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(arg0[i].getSuggestionAt(j))
        {
            isSpellCorrect = true;
            break;
        }               
     }        
 }
```

You can find the whole project from this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spelling_checker.htm). In above project you can see string is appended. Instead just change the above method onGetSuggestions..

Comment: Please post description with code..